# Xamarin.Forms - Mocking up an application for mobiles

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I need to mockup an application for mobiles (`Android` and `iPhone` mostly).

Then I have a couple of questions:

1- Is there any recent sample source code for download (`zip` or `GitHub`) which I can use on `Visual Studio 2015` and use as an starting point?. Something like the following:

[image]

2- When I step to the `prototyping` or `final development`, can I use native coding along with `Xamarin.Forms`?, I mean: `Xamarin.Forms` + [`Xamarion.Android` OR `Xamarin.iOS`]?, is that possible?

My definitions of `mockup` and `prototyping` are in accordance with this article:
https://blog.xamarin.com/rapid-mobile-app-prototyping-with-xamarin-forms/

Comment: there are dozens of sample apps available from Xamarin's site

Comment: By definition mockups are static and there are quite a few applications that provide features to aid in wireframe and mockups, i.e. Sketch is a very popular macOS-based used begin mobile graphic designers with hundreds of mobile-based templates...but that is just one in a very large market... After that there are dozens of sample apps on Xamarin's site with the Evolve app being the *largest* Xamarin.Forms based sample that I know of : https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve